# How can I know whether a step has been executed in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm have written a JUnit test case for logging into the application.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("SIGN IN")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("uname")).sendKeys("user_sam");
driver.findElement(By.id("pas")).sendKeys("special26");
driver.findElement(By.id("loginb")).click();
```

My requirement is if Login is successful I can simply check whether a new element is being displayed or not which was not there before login and verify that successfully.

But if while entering the data some issue happened or the user is providing an invalid input at that time how to check till what line the execution has been done successfully.

Comment: You could simply check if any validation error message is being shown..

Comment: I want it to be done using scripts only...no manual work..

Comment: Of course. You should write a script to do that

Comment: You can introduce logging mechanism. It will help you in debugging, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can log your statement and for more convenience you can also puts `System.out.println();` on each steps . That will display the flow of your statement on console and logger will log them so you can refer it later on.

Refer below :-

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/log4j-logging/

http://www.guru99.com/tutorial-on-log4j-and-logexpert-with-selenium.html

http://learn-automation.com/how-to-create-log-files-in-selenium/

Hope it will help you :)